# Show Localized value for HybrisEnumValue in Hybris Backoffice

Tags: localization, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

We are trying to show the localized value for a "dynamic" enum.

In our `backoffice-config.xml` We have something like this

```
<context type="CustomeType" component="base" merge-by="type">
    <y:base xmlns:y="http://www.hybris.com/cockpit/config/hybris">
        <y:labels>
            <y:label>customProperty.hybrisEnumValueProperty.name</y:label>
        </y:labels>
    </y:base>
</context>
```

With this we receive the default TypeName(Pk) in backoffice instead of the localized name. For the code it works just fine. Also for hmc it works as well.

Comment: By `dynamic`, you mean the values of the enums are coming from a different system i.e. static values from some properties file won't work for your case?

Comment: They are comming from the database. In the enum table, so they are not present in the items.xml file. Static properties would not work because they are being created/deleted dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add localization text for these enums like below.

mycoreextension-items.xml

```
<enumtype code="myenum" generate="true" dynamic="true">
  <value code="ENUM1" />
  <value code="ENUM2" />
</enumtype>
```

mycoreextension-locales_en.properties

```
type.myenum.name=My Enum Name
type.myenum.description=My enum description
type.myenum.enum1.name=My enum value 1
type.myenum.enum2.name=My enum value 1
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to get the enum "name" as in the hmc? Properties would work but those enums instances are created dynamically.

Comment: hmc will auto get these translation from translation files. May be you can manipulate translation service to add translation in runtime. We do some part of this manipulation for finding used words for creating new one. If I can remember more detail, I will update my answer.